# git push when commit --amend is done

Tags: git, gerrit

I have  done the following

1. `git commit`
2. `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`

I have received message similar to below:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8)
remote: Processing changes: new: 1, refs: 1, done    
remote: 
remote: New Changes:
remote:   https://gerrit.ericsson.se/abcde
remote: 
To ssh://gerrit.ericsson.se:29418/platform/cpp/control.git
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/for/master
```

1. Now in gerrit review I have received comments to change logic so did
2. `git commit --amend`

Now my question is if I again do`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master` [after `git commit --amend`]
Do I get new gerrit link?

If yes, is there any way that my changes get reflected in my old gerrit link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do not remove the `Change-Id` line from the commit message, Gerrit will group the new commit to the old issue. (see also [manual](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html))

Comment: i did git commit --amend -m "xxxx" and then git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master. i got new gerrit link and new change id

Comment: Sure, because you overwrote the complete message with the `-m`.

Comment: okay. So do you mean that if  had done git commit --amend only, then i would have got new patch set loaded in old gerrit link?

Comment: If there is a change in commit message then change-ID would also be changed ?

Comment: The `Change-Id` is part of the commit message, see e.g. [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/54922/). Don't overwrite the whole message, do `git commit --amend` to open your `$EDITOR` and feel free to change anything except the `Change-Id` line on the bottom.