# `git-review` after `git commit --amend -F file` - a new review?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-review

I used to do git amend in the following simple way `git commit --amend`. Recently I started using message from file option (`-F`), like so: `git commit --amend -F my_git_message.txt`.

My workflow includes [git-review](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review) tool which I call after each commit: `git review --reviewers user1 user2`.

After I started using `-F` option when amending, seems like `git-review` started creating a new review, instead of amending the change to an old review. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because you will reset the change-id that's in the commit message. If you're not changing the commit message, use `git commit --amend --no-edit` instead to avoid that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push when commit --amend is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905670/git-push-when-commit-amend-is-done)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgerrit%5D+%5Bgit%5D+amend